# Query delta changes to Hive metadata from last month

Tags: hive, hiveql

We have a hive metastore in mysql db. Use case  is to query all the updates alters or deletes done to the hive metadata from past one month. We need to query this information to update an existing data catalog about this metadata.

We need only the delta changes happened from past query pull. How to query changes from hive metastore tables to check changes happened on a metadata during a time interval?

Tried few query sample to pull metadata.

We need to query this information to update an existing data catalog about this metadata.

We need only the delta changes happened from past query pull. How to query changes from hive metastore tables to check changes happened on a metadata during a time interval?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: SELECT c.* FROM hive.TBLS t  JOIN hive.DBS d  ON t.DB_ID = d.DB_ID  JOIN hive.SDS s  ON t.SD_ID = s.SD_ID  JOIN hive.COLUMNS_V2 c  ON s.CD_ID = c.CD_ID  WHERE TBL_NAME = 'airline_tweets' AND d.NAME= 'default'  ORDER by INTEGER_IDX; For example this query gives changes made to table airline_tweets metadata. similarly i need to pull data for all table between a data range,. Say some one altered the table to add a column , other chnaged a data format. need to pull all these changes from meta store.

Comment: No, please put your example in the question by editing it